# Why am I getting an old value for a text file in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, git

I am trying to put the last known git version in an about page in my app. I'm keeping track of the last commit number by using a gitVersion.txt file which contains one line - the commit number.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
NSString *gitFile = [NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"gitVersion" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *gitVersion = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:gitFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSString *labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Build: %@",[gitVersion substringToIndex:7]];
```

The problem is that ever since I first did this, it's always used the first commit I entered, no matter how many times I updated the file with a new commit.

Note that even when I produce an ipa and check the .app for gitVersion.txt, it has the old value. This tells me it's cached somewhere and I don't know how to update it...

**Additional Information:**

I've done the usual 'Clean' and even 'Clean Build Folder' options. I also tried 'Reset Content and Settings' in the simulator but no luck.

Comment: How you are updating the file ?

Comment: I update the file with a text editor right before I tag a release.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have 2 gitVersion.txt files and I've been updating the one that iOS doesn't even look at.

How I made this error:

1. I created gitVersion.txt(A) in the root directory (where the .xcodeproj can be found).
2. I unknowingly added the file to my Xcode project in a different folder than the root, selecting 'Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)'. This created gitVersion.txt(B).
3. Anytime I updated the git version, I was updating gitVersion.txt(A), while the app was pulling from the original git revision found in gitVersion.txt(B)!

How I solved the problem:

1. I deleted gitVersion.txt(B) with `git rm ProjectFolder/gitVersion.txt`
2. I deleted gitVersion.txt(B) from the Xcode project.
3. I added gitVersion.txt(A) to the Xcode project, unchecking 'Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)'.
4. (optional) Sought repentance from the git gods for cursing their name...

My prayers were answered and it now updates from the root directory just fine!